# Unity touch delta position incorrect with different screen sizes

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine, touch

I am New to C# Unity I just learned few things to get started and
I am making a simple 2D touch control With touch delta to Translate The GameObject With Touch Anywhere on the screen and drag to move along the touch directions Not to Touch Position.

For example Rise Up 2D Game Like control where Sphere is being controlled by touch drag.

But The Problem is When I test it on different screen sizes The Translate or Touch speed Is different.

If The screen size is small like 640x800 Touch speed is slow.

If The screen size is Big like 1440x2560 Touch speed is Fast.

Here is the example code i am using.

```
    private Touch firstTouch;
    public Vector3 dragDistance;
    private Vector3 StopDrag;
    public Transform player;

    void FixedUpdate () {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {    firstTouch = Input.GetTouch(0);
                if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
            {
                dragDistance = firstTouch.deltaPosition;
                player.transform.Translate(dragDistance / 100 );
            }
                if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Stationary)
            {
                dragDistance = StopDrag ;
            }}}
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE SORRY FOR MY BAD ENGLISH

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, the solution to your problem would be changing the line

```
    dragDistance = firstTouch.deltaPosition;
```

to

```
    Vector2 dragDistanceUnscaled = firstTouch.deltaPosition;
    dragDistance = new Vector2(dragDistanceUnscaled.x / Screen.Width,
                               dragDistanceUnscaled.y / Screen.Height)
```

Also, at least as far as I know, you only need a `Vector2`, and not a `Vector3` for dragDistance.

Comment: good job benediktas

Answer (score 1):

The problem is at this line:
**player.transform.Translate(dragDistance / 100 );**

The '100' value is relative to the frame speed of the device itself.
So, **the fix should be use Time.deltaTime * value.**
Where value can be any float, 100, for instance.
With this the expected transform will be the same for any device, regardless if it is high or low quality.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change FixedUpdate() to Update(). It should work